# Hash set with static initilazation parameters

Tags: java

I was going through some classes in which I have found one hashset implementation like this

```
public static HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    static{
        set.add("abc");
        set.add("def");
        set.add("eghi");

    }
```

In `static block`, I just want to know what this pattern known as,`static` initialization.Does it mean initially when the jvm is up we have the set with `initialized` values.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

```
   StaticInitializer:
        static Block
```

If you see [JLS-8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized (§12.4.2). Together with any field initializers for class variables (§8.3.2), static initializers may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.

**Note :**

> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in scope. See §8.3.2.3 for the precise rules governing forward reference to class variables.

Comment: The Note isn't relevant to static initializer blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The static block only gets called once at the time of class loading, no matter how many objects of that type you create.

Static block will have no access to the non static instance variables or methods.

You can use static block to handle exceptions during initialization.

The fact that static blocks are executed during the loading of class and even before the constructor is called, this feature can be used in **singleton pattern**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is static initialization block.

**About Static initialization block:**

A static initialization block is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword.

**When it will load:**

A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.